# How to concatenate columns and pivot keeping columns information in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have an input df:

```
input_ = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
[
    ['X_val', 'Y_val1', 'Y_val2', 'Y_val3'],
    [1, 10, 11, 31],
    [2, 20, 12, 21],
    [3, 30, 13, 11],])
```

and want to concat every y-value but still distinct where the value came from for plotting and analysis,
I have multiple files with variable number of Y columns and ended up concatenating them column by column and extending with multiplied value, but was wondering if there is a better solution, because mine is terribly tedious.

```
expected_output_ = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
[
    ['X_val', 'Y_val' 'Y_type'],
    [1, 10, 'Y_val1'],
    [1, 11, 'Y_val2'],
    [1, 31, 'Y_val3'],
    [2, 20, 'Y_val1'],
    [2, 12, 'Y_val2'],
    [2, 21, 'Y_val3'],
    [3, 30, 'Y_val1'],
    [3, 13, 'Y_val2'],
    [3, 11, 'Y_val3'],])
```

Comment: Your DataFarme needs to be structured properly. Use `columns` attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) :

```
input_.melt(
    id_vars=['X_val'],
    value_vars=['Y_val1', 'Y_val2', 'Y_val3'],
    var_name='Y_type',
    value_name='Y_val'
).sort_values(['X_val'], ignore_index=True)
```

Alternatively, as suggested by @Vishnudev, you can also use the following variation, especially for large number of similarly named `Y_val*` columns:

```
input_.melt(
    id_vars=['X_val'],
    value_vars=input_.filter(regex='Y_val').columns,
    var_name='Y_type',
    value_name='Y_val'
).sort_values(['X_val'], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    X_val   Y_type  Y_val
0       1   Y_val1     10
1       1   Y_val2     11
2       1   Y_val3     31
3       2   Y_val1     20
4       2   Y_val2     12
5       2   Y_val3     21
6       3   Y_val1     30
7       3   Y_val2     13
8       3   Y_val3     11
```

Optionally, you can rearrange the column sequence if you like.

Comment: You might wanna add `input_.filter(regex='Y_val').columns` in `value_vars` for better code.

Comment: @Vishnudev That's a good suggestion especially for large number of similarly named columns.  Thanks for the suggestion as well as the formatting edit too!